# Перемещение безрамочного окна при нажатии в определенной области

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, framelesswindowhint, mousemoveevent

У меня есть методы, благодаря которым, я перемещаю **`desktop`** приложения по рабочему столу *Windows*. 
Если я зажимаю в любом место своего приложения, то происходит перенос его.

Как сделать так, что только при зажатой определенной области эти методы срабатывали.

```
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        delta = QPoint(event.globalPosition().toPoint() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]  вашего кода и как-то покажите на изображении ту область, нажав на которую вы хотите перетаскивать окно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Обратите внимание, что у меня **`PyQt5`**, если у вас **`PyQt6`** - внесите нужные изменения.

Один из возможных вариантов, выглядит примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TitleBar(QWidget):
    height = 35

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TitleBar, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.title = QLabel("My Own Bar")        
        self.title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.title.setFixedHeight(self.height)
        self.title.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: white;
        """)

        self.closeButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_close)
        self.closeButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #DC143C;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.maxButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.maxButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_maximize)
        self.maxButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #32CD32;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.hideButton = QPushButton(' ')
        self.hideButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click_hide)
        self.hideButton.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height: {};
            width: {};
            margin-right: 3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
        """.format(self.height/1.7,self.height/1.7))

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.hideButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.maxButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.pressing = False
        self.maximaze = False
        
        self.hideButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus) 
        self.maxButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)  
        self.closeButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        super(TitleBar, self).resizeEvent(QResizeEvent)
        self.title.setFixedWidth(self.parent.width())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.parent.move(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement))
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pressing = False

    def on_click_close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def on_click_maximize(self):
        self.maximaze = not self.maximaze
        if self.maximaze:    
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)
        else:
            self.parent.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

    def on_click_hide(self):
        self.parent.showMinimized()


class StatusBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.showMessage("Hello StatusBar!")

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Status bar...")
        self.label.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #23272a;  
            font-size: 12px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            color: white;
        """)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def showMessage(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)        
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #2c2f33;   
        """)

        self.label = QLabel("Hello Label")
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: white;
        """)
        
        self.title_bar = TitleBar(self) 
        
        self.status_bar = StatusBar(self)

        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.title_bar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.status_bar, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]